# Mass web.config modification for deployments

Tags: powershell, devops

I know this has been brought up in a large amount of threads, but so far I haven't come across a solution that is working for me. Basically we have around 300 websites that all have unique database connection strings in the web.configs. When development releases a new build, we are having to go and manually copy the connection strings from a backup of the web.config in to the new web.config. With 300 sites, this is time consuming and error prone. I want to remove the human element from it and I'm looking towards PowerShell to help with this.

My thought process is as follows:

Script that searches existing web.config for connectionString info, dumps it to a holding file.

Script that reads holding file and then replaces appropriate values in new web.config file

I've tried several solutions in other threads, such as:

[Editing Web Config file using Microsoft PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894552/editing-web-config-file-using-microsoft-powershell)

but I just get error after error no matter what I try. My latest script:

```html
    $cfg = [xml](gc E:\scripts\web.config)
    $cfg.configuration.connectionStrings.add|%{
   $_.connectionString = $_.connectionString -replace "QA", "PRODUCTION";
}
$cfg.Save("E:\scripts\Web.config");
```

is returning:

```html
Property 'connectionString' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At E:\scripts\WebConfig.ps1:4 char:7
+    $_. <<<< connectionString = $_.connectionString -replace "QA", "PRODUCTION";
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (connectionString:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

I've been fighting with this all day, so if someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. I'm not looking for someone to write a solution for me, just looking for pointers as I can't be the only person out there who has had this challenge.

Comment: If you want to get rid of that error.. Replace the equals sign with -eq

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
$cfg = [xml](gc E:\scripts\web.config)
    $cfg.configuration.connectionStrings.add|%{
   $_.connectionString -eq $_.connectionString -replace "QA", "PRODUCTION";
}
$cfg.Save("E:\scripts\Web.config");
```

Basically your issue here is you used the wrong operator in:

```
%{
   $_.connectionString = $_.connectionString -replace "QA", "PRODUCTION";
}
```

You had a = when you should have been using -eq. 
Using = will set a value.
Using -eq will detect if the value equals another value.