# PowerShell replace text between two string

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to modify `config.xml`.
`config.xml` content is

```
<command>
some lines here 2
</command>
some lines here 3
```

So I want to replace the content between <`command>` and `</command>`. Here is what I tried doing

```
$Replace = Get-Content D:\Temp\Replace.txt
$ReplaceWith = Get-Content D:\Temp\ReplaceWith.txt

$regex = '(<command>\d*).*?(</command>\d*)'
$Replace -replace $regex, $ReplaceWith
```

But its not working. Need help.

Comment: Use `-Raw`  with `Get-Content` and also add `(?s)` at the regex start. Also, if your `replaceWith.txt` contains *plain text* (not a specifically formatted regex replacement string) and if you have `$` in the replacement, you need to double them and remove `\d*` and parentheses.

Comment: What about `(<command>)[\S\s]+(<\/command>)`? ;).

Comment: so will the regex look like this $regex = '(?s)(<command>\d*).*?(</command>)(?s)'

Comment: [don't parse `xml` with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Instead, read as `xml` and either dot index (`$myconfig.topnode.othernode.command`) or [`SelectNode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894552/editing-web-config-file-using-microsoft-powershell/17899255#17899255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks gms0ulman. I was able to do this using reading as xml in powershell, below was the code

```
$ReplaceWith = Get-Content C:\psscript.ps1 -Raw
[xml]$ConfigXml = Get-Content "c:\config.xml" -Raw
$SelectCommandNode = $ConfigXml.SelectSingleNode("//command")
$SelectCommandNode.InnerText = $ReplaceWith
$ConfigXml.Save("c:\config.xmll")
```